# obtain URL from a local WSDL in Maven Project

Tags: java, web-services, maven, url, wsdl2java

Good morning everybody. 
I am new in Web Service. 
Under Eclipse, i have a Maven Project. 
This project is written in Java. 
I have copied a WSDL in src/main/resources. 
First, i want to access to the physical address of this local WSDL. 
Second, i want create an URL from this WSDL local address. 
I need the URL of the WSDL, to call a distant Web Service. 
The Web Service run Under JBoss and is a SOAP WebService. 
I just want to call this Web Service, 
and, for this, i need to obtain the URL from the local WSDL of the Web Service 
 (WSDL located in the project, in src/main/resources). 
I thank you in advance for your help. 
  Thomas

PS: this question will be trivial for you, probably, but i am really new in Web Service and especially in calling WS, and i want to learn. 

 Thank you for your understanding

Here is the pom.xml (i have not written this pom, i only update the project from svn)
=>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>fr.sog.routine.routineinitprog</groupId>
<artifactId>routineinitprog</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Outil</name>
<description>Outil pour initialiser </description>
-<dependencies>
-<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.7</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

-<build>
<!-- force le nom du jar créé sans numéro de version -->
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
-<resources>

<!-- filtrage pour build-info.properties -->
-<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
-<includes>
<include>**/*.properties</include>
</includes>
</resource>

<!-- filtrage pour build-info.properties -->
-<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<filtering>false</filtering>
-<includes>
<include>**/*.key</include>
</includes>
</resource>
</resources>
-<plugins>

<!-- Compilateur java -->
-<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
-<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
</configuration>

</plugin>


-<plugin>
<!-- permet d'utiliser la servlet BuildInfoServlet présente dans bt1core -->
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
-<executions>
-<execution>
<phase>validate</phase>
-<goals>
<goal>create</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>


-<configuration>
<doCheck>false</doCheck>
<doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
<timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
</configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- Packaging en Jar executable -->
-<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
-<executions>
-<execution>
-<goals>
<goal>shade</goal>
</goals>
<phase>package</phase>
</execution>
</executions>


-<configuration>
-<transformers>
-<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
-<manifestEntries>
<Main-Class>fr.msa.agora.routineinitprog.LanceurAutomate</Main-Class>
</manifestEntries>
</transformer>
</transformers>
</configuration>
</plugin>
-<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
-<executions>
-<execution>
<id>copy-to-root</id>
<phase>install</phase>
-<configuration>
-<tasks>
<echo>copying : ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</echo>
<copy todir="." file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
</tasks>
</configuration>
-<goals>
<goal>run</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
-<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.13</version>
-<configuration>
</configuration>
<!-- <executions> -->
<!-- <execution> -->
<!-- <goals> -->
<!-- <goal>integration-test</goal> -->
<!-- <goal>verify</goal> -->
<!-- </goals> -->
<!-- </execution> -->
<!-- </executions> -->
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
-<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
-<scm>
<connection>scm:svn:http://gliese.agora.msanet/svn/PROG/Outils/routineinitprog/trunk</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:svn:http://gliese.agora.msanet/svn/PROG/Outils/routineinitprog/trunk</developerConnection>
<url>http://iota.agora.msanet:8080/sventon/repos/PROG/list/routineinitprog/trunk/</url>
</scm>
-<distributionManagement>
-<repository>
<id>agora-tech-release</id>
<name>Agora Technique Release</name>
<url>http://gliese.agora.msanet/nexus/content/repositories/agora-tech-release</url>
</repository>
+<snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: What style of JAX-WS implementation you are using.. can you post your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot Chetan. I wiil add the pom.xml.

Comment: is build successful for this pom.xml, what type of packaging you are using